# XSLT 1.0 recursive string replace function returns empty document

Tags: xml, xslt

I thought I'd take a stab at answering a [question](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/29903/transformar-url-xslt) on the Spanish StackOverflow. The question involves the use of a recursive template to handle string replacement in XSLT 1.0. I was able to eliminate the error message by enclosing the parameter arguments in single quotes, but I'm still getting a blank output result.

Here is the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<document>
    <URL>[sitio]/PublishingImages/[nombreimagen].jpg</URL>
</document>
```

Here is the desired output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<document>
    <URL>[sitio]/PublishingImages/_t/[nombreimagen]_jpg.jpg</URL>
</document>
```

Here is the XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

    <xsl:template name="string-replace">
        <xsl:param name="text" />
            <xsl:param name="pattern" />
                <xsl:param name="replace-with" />
              <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test="contains($text, $pattern)">
                            <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($text, $pattern)" />
                            <xsl:value-of select="$replace-with" />
                                <xsl:call-template name="string-replace">
                                    <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring-after($text, $pattern)" />
                                    <xsl:with-param name="pattern" select="$pattern" />
                                    <xsl:with-param name="replace-with" select="$replace-with" />
                                    </xsl:call-template>
                        </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:otherwise>
                            <xsl:value-of select="$text" />
                        </xsl:otherwise>
                    </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template> 

    <xsl:template match="URL">
        <xsl:variable name="ImageUrl"><xsl:value-of select="URL"/></xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="primerreplace">
        <xsl:call-template name="string-replace">
            <xsl:with-param name="text" select="$ImageUrl" />
            <xsl:with-param name="pattern" select="'PublishingImages'" />
            <xsl:with-param name="replace-with" select="'PublishingImages/_t'" />
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:variable>                            
    <xsl:variable name="segundoreplace">
        <xsl:call-template name="string-replace">
            <xsl:with-param name="text" select="$primerreplace" />
            <xsl:with-param name="pattern" select="'.jpg'" />
            <xsl:with-param name="replace-with" select="'_jpg.jpg'" />
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:variable> 
    <xsl:value-of select="$segundoreplace" />
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the variable declaration of `ImageUrl` from this...

```
<xsl:variable name="ImageUrl"><xsl:value-of select="URL"/></xsl:variable>
```

To this...

```
<xsl:variable name="ImageUrl"><xsl:value-of select="."/></xsl:variable>
```

Or better still, just this...

```
<xsl:variable name="ImageUrl" select="." />
```

This is because you are in a template matching `URL`, so doing `<xsl:value-of select="URL" />` was looking for a child element called `URL` of the current `URL` element.

Comment: Thanks... I almost had it!